# Trigger error when using a particular third-party or java.* method or constructor

Tags: java, lombok

Is there some Java library that connects to the compiler that can allow you to add a warning or even failure when using any method and output a text recommending something else?

For instance, if I want a user calling `Arrays.asList()` to get a warning or even failure and recommend another method to use?

Comment: Just a suggestion, I would considering using `grep` with a git pre-commit hook or continuous build server script. This would be much lighter-weight that what you're requesting. Feedback would be delayed, but it may suffice -- your first line of defense should be team convention that "We will not use this method", second line of defense would be a simple script.

Comment: Isn't `@deprecated` precisely used for this purpose?

Comment: Can't add annotations to third-party libraries, @BruceWayne; well, not without including the source.

Comment: @DavidS, I agree, that's why I always wrap third party libraries. As an added bonus, I am not coupled to the library.

Comment: @BruceWayne, it's one thing to wrap a third party library with your own interface, but including all of the source code in the compilation path of your project seems not so great. Just my opinion.

Comment: @BruceWayne wrapping is not always possible. Some classes might be final and so can some methods. Delegation works i guess but it feels kind of messy to have maintain that. DavidS ... yes, communication is one way, but that can be hard to maintain depending on project and company size. It would be better to just be able to enforce it. Grep can become tricky to handle various ways to invoke a method. Full package name, vs fully imported vs partially imported vs statically imported.

Comment: I would imagine some form of AOP programming might work. Take a class and a String for method name, and find usages for that method. Not sure where to start though.

Comment: ...What is your problem with `Arrays.asList`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Don't new File() some shit. There is code for that. Zero redundancy is a dream I would like to enforce.

Comment: I hope you have good judgement and the authority to enforce your dream, or else this is going to end with bunch of grouchy developers and bruised egos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for something that plugs into the compiler, so you might try [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info/), which lets you write custom compile errors by plugging into the compiler API.

(Error Prone, and [tools built on top of it that aren't open-sourced yet](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en/us/pubs/archive/41876.pdf), are exactly what Google uses for exactly this problem.  Source: I sit next to the Error Prone team.)

An example check, to flag usages of `Class.getClass()`, is [here](https://github.com/google/error-prone/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/errorprone/bugpatterns/GetClassOnClass.java).  (That is, you already had a `Class` object, and then you called `getClass()` on that, which returns `Class.class`, which is just silly.)

Comment: (That said, `Arrays.asList` is a method most people should use _more_ often, not less.)

Comment: Splendid ( Simon Burns ). I will investigate this futher hopefully tomorrow, but looks promising :)

Comment: Unfortunately I get a bunch of errors when I use the maven plugin during the maven build process. I am using Java 8. It might be because I use $ in many places, for instance $Executor for my own executor class, sometimes $ $ for T t; There might be other issues causing the many compiler errors, not sure if it is a faulty/incompatible compiler. Not sure if fixing those things will help. In maven when something fails, it tends to fail everywhere.

Comment: When I use the maven plugin, i get the following error: http://pastebin.com/NcmEicyg

But I am able to partially use Intellij plugin while removing the maven dependency, which allows me to build the project from outside without errorprone compiler and get certain warnings and errors inside Intellij. I have to use the rebuild project though to renew the error messages but that is working somewhat. 

I am getting some warnings regarding the accessing static method from a variable over class.

Comment: Is there a way to tell errorprone to ignore these warnings? Is error-prone loaded with a set of "bugpatterns"? Is it all of these: https://github.com/google/error-prone/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/errorprone/bugpatterns 

How can I override for isntance 
Warning:(111, 21) java: [StaticAccessedFromInstance] Static method info should not be accessed from an object instance; instead use Log.info
    (see http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/StaticAccessedFromInstance)
  Did you mean 'Log.info( EntityError.class, Gson.asString(this) );'?

Comment: I want to continue to access it as is. I have my reasons :)

Comment: I am still getting other errors though, even with Intellij plugin. Might have to do with the class using another class named $DatabaseConfig

Comment: No, I renamed and still getting the same error: http://pastebin.com/umWd18m6

I understand that this is a different question now, but I understand that you are sitting next to the errorprone team, so perhaps you could ask for their attention with regards to these bugs. I will post a new question and send you the link :)

Comment: Yes, Error Prone has a built-in set of bug patterns.  [Yes](http://errorprone.info/docs/flags), you can disable them.  (No, I don't believe there's ever a good reason to disable StaticAccessedFromInstance.)

Comment: The error in http://pastebin.com/NcmEicyg happens because you're using Lombok, and Error Prone uses javac9, and Lombok doesn't work with javac9 yet (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=757). I'm not sure about the second issue. If you have a repro, can you file a bug at http://github.com/google/error-prone/issues?

Comment: @LiamMiller-Cushon Is there a way to tell errorprone to use a java 8 compiler. This must have been a quite recent compiler update since 9 hasn't been around for so long. Right?

Answer (score 0):

i believe Eclipse will be good enough to take care of such things .

Eclipse - > preferences ->Java->Compiler ->Error /warnings ,

you can play with options here. but to make to make it more and more generic , you need to use eclipse provided APIs

Comment: Not such a great answer. The first part doesn't solve the OPs problem because he's asking about third-party libraries, and the second part is too vague, and the OP didn't even say he's using Eclipse or that his team members are obligated too.

Comment: I am not using Eclipse and I am not sure it's worth looking up since I am pretty sure it won't be able to do what I am asking for.. are you sure, that I can for instance type in a class and method and have it complain?

Comment: what IDE you people are using for development .